# In what order do you watch the fullmetal alchemist?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

When I ask this question I don't mean between fullmetal alchemist and fullmetal brotherhood. I mean witch do you watch as a series.

Comment: What do you mean by series? As far as I know there's only FMA and FMA:B and you can't "watch" manga. Have you seen [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullmetal_Alchemist)?

Comment: Both Fullmetal Alchemist and Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood are series in and of themselves. If you're asking what order to watch the episodes in either serirs: in order? Start at episode one, then two and three, and do on until you've seen them all.

Answer (score 4):

Both series are in fact separate entities.

The series named simply Fullmetal Alchemist was created first and went in a very different direction from the source material once the basic premise was established. Brotherhood instead closely adapts the original manga in it's entirety.

Edward and Alphonse lost their respective parts trying to resurrect their mother, Scar and the Homunculi exist and both series start off in Lior but that's where the similarities end. Major details like the origins of the Homunculi and the overarching plot are entirely different.